# How to install specific version of ruby (1.8.6) with rbenv?

Tags: ruby

I have some old source code that runs on ruby 1.8 and rails 2.3 . I have rbenv on my system. How can I install exactly this version of ruby (v1.8.6) with rbenv?

```
$ rbenv install 1.8.6
Downloading ruby-1.8.6.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.8/ruby-1.8.6.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-1.8.6...

WARNING: ruby-1.8.6 is past its end of life and is now unsupported.
It no longer receives bug fixes or critical security updates.

ruby-build: use readline from homebrew

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.14.2 using ruby-build 20190423)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/_w/98n31_kn03qfjt51p2hmrfqh0000gp/T/ruby-build.20190701155134.45412
Results logged to /var/folders/_w/98n31_kn03qfjt51p2hmrfqh0000gp/T/ruby-build.20190701155134.45412.log

Last 10 log lines:
/var/folders/_w/98n31_kn03qfjt51p2hmrfqh0000gp/T/ruby-build.20190701155134.45412 ~
/var/folders/_w/98n31_kn03qfjt51p2hmrfqh0000gp/T/ruby-build.20190701155134.45412/ruby-1.8.6 /var/folders/_w/98n31_kn03qfjt51p2hmrfqh0000gp/T/ruby-build.20190701155134.45412 ~
checking build system type... i686-apple-darwin18.2.0
checking host system type... i686-apple-darwin18.2.0
checking target system type... i686-apple-darwin18.2.0
checking for gcc... /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2
checking for C compiler default output file name...
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

I've tried this solution but it does not work for me...
https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/999

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to run `CC=/usr/bin/gcc rbenv install 1.8.6`. To check if you have gcc installed run `which gcc`

Comment: hmm...nope...gives me back the exact same error .... https://pastebin.com/mN0waqPR

Comment: please update your question with contents of `config.log`

Comment: I do not know the location of config.log

Comment: How about `/var/folders/_w/98n31_kn03qfjt51p2hmrfqh0000gp/T/ruby-build.20190701155134.45412.log`?

Comment: Tried that one..it just contains the 10 line output shown above.